# Reports for VS 2013 didn't work

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2013, report

I've a problem with a reports in VS 2013. I used a report viewer and it didn't work, when I clicked on create a new report and nothing ever has. So, I downloaded a crystal reports `SP9` version 13, and I clicked on create a new report and I get error:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002.
```

Why reports didn't work? What to use for reports in VS 2013?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this may be caused by several issues:

1- Multiple versions of crystal reports are installed on the machine.

2- Multiple references to the VS environment.

3- Crystal report viewer not installed correctly.

you need to check these things from:

1- The web.config assembly for crystal report, you may need to change the version manually.

```
 <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
```

2- Right click on your solution >> Select Add Reference >> change the tab to recent you can check how many versions are added as references to your solution, or may be there is not any references that you may need to add one where you can from Tab (Browse) where you should select the location of the DLLs you have installed.